# Operator overloaded functions as friend?

Tags: c++, c++11, friend

I have a class that represents a special number.

```
class SecretInteger
{
private:
    unsigned int *data;
    size_t length;

public: 
    SecretInteger operator+(const SecretInteger other) const;
}
```

I can't allow any other part of my code have access to the `data` variable. However, my `operator+` function MUST be able to see it. Usually in this case I know that using the `friend` keyword is the only way to do it. However when I write:

```
friend SecretInteger operator+(const SecretInteger other);
```

It claims that the `operator+` cannot be declared as friend, even though I've previously wrote `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const SecretInteger val);` and it works fine.

What options do I have available to me? If I have a public method like

`const *unsigned int getData() const;` I think even then it doesn't actually make the variable returned `const` right? I'd really prefer not to have a `getData()` method and instead just declare the functions that have access as `friend`.

Comment: You're declaring `operator+` as a member function so it could access `data`, isn't it?

Comment: ~~It cannot access `other`'s data which makes it impossible for me to perform arithmetic.~~

Comment: Side-note: Even if you insist on a member function for the overload, there is no reason to accept the argument by value. Surely `const SecretInteger& other` is what you want.

Comment: @ShadowRanger why is it bad to make the operator overload a member function? What's the alternative? If you mean making a friend function, it doesn't allow me to do that. Also `SecretInteger` is an immutable class so I thought pass by value is totally okay as I don't plan on making any changes to `other` at any point.

Comment: @Hatefiend No, it can. Did you try with it?

Comment: @Hatefiend: If you don't plan on making any changes, but accept the argument by value, then you're pointlessly constructing new copies. A const reference means you avoid constructing anything, using a reference to the existing instance instead of reconstructing (and destroying later), saving a bunch of pointless work. As for avoiding member functions for non-in-place overloads, that's [been covered at great length](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4622330/364696); I won't recapitulate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't declare a member function as a `friend`, `friend` is to give non-member functions access to internals, and a one operand overload of `operator+` is a member function.

In any event, if you implement the binary operators properly, you shouldn't need to give out friendship at all. Implement `+=` as a member function (no need for `friend`, a class is always "friends" with itself), then implement a non-member `+` operator in terms of `+=`, which uses `+=`'s access to the internals to avoid the whole issue of friendship.

The basic rules for overloading [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/364696) and should help a lot.

Comment: Wait.... why does my program have access to `other`'s internals? In Java this would not be the case. What's going on here? In my `operator+` I am able to access private member `data` of both `this` and `other`. Why?

Comment: Oh so if you have `class A` and ANY function in `A` that takes in a parameter of type `A`, it will have private access to that variable?

Comment: @Hatefiend: [Java gives you access too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29068196/364696). `private` means "only accessible to this class", so any `SecretInteger` can access the `private`s of any `Secretinteger`, itself or a different instance. `private` is for interface purposes, it's not a security feature to firewall instances from one another.